# Is there any priority of Virtual Services applied for the same host?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have two namespaces.

application:

- serviceA
- serviceB
- Virtual Service C -> B

  ```
   gateway: mesh
   host: serviceC.external.svc.cluster.local
   destination: serviceB.application.svc.cluster.local
   exportTo: . (same namespace)
  ```

external:

- serviceC
- Virtual Service C -> C

  ```
   gateway: mesh
   host: serviceC.external.svc.cluster.local
   destination: serviceC.external.svc.cluster.local
   exportTo: * (all namespaces)
  ```

Question: which Virtual Service handles requests form serviceA to serviceC.external.svc.cluster.local? Is there any priority?

Istio says “A VirtualService can only be fragmented this way if it is bound to a gateway. Host merging is not supported in sidecars.”

I’ve tried to reproduce this situation and Virtual Service C -> B handles request and routs it to ServiceB.

Comment: Can we rely on this behavior or it is undocumented?

Comment: Istio version is 1.2.2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly there are some documented materials you should check out:

1. You need to get familiar with the [Routing rule precedence](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#precedence).

> Multiple rules for a given destination in a configuration file are
>   evaluated in the order they appear. The first rule on the list has the
>   highest priority.

2. You can also use the [Rules Configuration](https://istio-releases.github.io/v0.1/docs/concepts/traffic-management/rules-configuration.html) which can be setup with a specific precedence:

> Multiple route rules could be applied to the same destination. The
>   order of evaluation of rules corresponding to a given destination,
>   when there is more than one, can be specified by setting the
>   precedence field of the rule.
>
> The precedence field is an optional integer value, 0 by default. Rules
>   with higher precedence values are evaluated first. If there is more
>   than one rule with the same precedence value the order of evaluation
>   is undefined.

3. I see that you are using different namespaces. You should also get familiar with [Cross-namespace configuration sharing](https://istio.io/docs/ops/traffic-management/deploy-guidelines/#cross-namespace-configuration-sharing).

Please let me know if that helped.